# Hiding of figures instead of overlapping

Tags: python, matplotlib, tkinter, pip, sensors

I have a function that should simulate a sensor. For this task I have implemented a function that reads the mouse-click and puts a little Circle in the Frame.
With a Button I start then the simulated growing of a sensor wave with this function:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib
import math
import numpy as np
import time
matplotlib.use('TkAgg')

from matplotlib.backends.backend_tkagg import FigureCanvasTkAgg, 
NavigationToolbar2Tk

from matplotlib.backend_bases import key_press_handler

import sys
if sys.version_info[0] < 3:
    import Tkinter as Tk
else:
    import tkinter as Tk

root = Tk.Tk()
root.wm_title("Localization")

x = [0. , 100.]
y = [0. , 100.]

fig1 = plt.figure()
ax1 = fig1.add_subplot(111, aspect='equal')
ax1.axis([min(x), max(x), min(y), max(y)])

# a tk.DrawingArea
canvas1 = FigureCanvasTkAgg(fig1, master=root)
canvas1.draw()
canvas1.get_tk_widget().pack(side=Tk.LEFT, fill=Tk.X, expand=1)

toolbar = NavigationToolbar2Tk(canvas1, root)
toolbar.update()
canvas1._tkcanvas.pack(side=Tk.TOP, fill=Tk.BOTH, expand=1)

coords = []
distanceToMid = []
timer = []

def onclick(event):
    counter = 0

    if event.button:
        print('button=%d, x=%d, y=%d, xdata=%f, ydata=%f' %
            (event.button, event.x, event.y, event.xdata, event.ydata)) 
        plt.plot(event.xdata, event.ydata, ',')

    #right click sets the black node circles
    if  (event.button == 3 and counter < 9):
        ix,iy = event.xdata, event.ydata
        coords.append((ix,iy))
        circle = plt.Circle((event.xdata,event.ydata), 0.5, color='black', 
alpha=1)
        ax1.add_artist(circle)
        fig1.canvas.draw()
        counter += 1

    #double-click imitates the wave from the middle 
    if event.dblclick:
        for i in range(1, 72):
            circle_mid = plt.Circle((50,50), i ,color='red', alpha=1, fill=1)
            ax1.add_artist(circle_mid)
            fig1.canvas.draw()
        circle_clear = plt.Circle((50,50), 72, color="white", alpha=1, fill=1)
        ax1.add_artist(circle_clear)
        for j in range(0,len(coords)):
            circle_loc = plt.Circle(coords[j],0.5,color="black", alpha=1, fill=1)
            ax1.add_artist(circle_loc)
        fig1.canvas.draw()



cid = fig1.canvas.mpl_connect('button_press_event', onclick)

def _quit():
    root.quit()     # stops mainloop
    root.destroy()  # this is necessary on Windows to prevent
                    # Fatal Python Error: PyEval_RestoreThread: NULL tstate

button1 = Tk.Button(master=root, text='Quit', command=_quit)
button1.pack(side=Tk.LEFT)

#Shows the 9 node coordinates
def callback():
        print (coords)

button2 = Tk.Button(master=root, text="Show node coords", command=callback)
button2.pack(side=Tk.LEFT)

def startpositioning():
    for i in range(0,len(coords)):
        start_time = time.time()
        for j in range(1,142):
            circle_loc = plt.Circle(coords[i], j, color='green', alpha=1, fill=1)
            ax1.add_artist(circle_loc)
            fig1.canvas.draw()
        timer.append(time.time() - start_time)
        circle_clear = plt.Circle((50,50), 72, color="white", alpha=1, fill=1)
        ax1.add_artist(circle_clear)
        for j in range(0,len(coords)):
            circle_loc = plt.Circle(coords[j],0.5,color="black", alpha=1, fill=1)
            ax1.add_artist(circle_loc)
        fig1.canvas.draw()
    print (timer)


button3 = Tk.Button(master=root, text="Start positioning from nodes", 
command=startpositioning)
button3.pack(side=Tk.LEFT)

def distancemid():
    for i in range(0,len(coords)):
        distanceToMid.append(math.hypot(coords[i][0] - 50, coords[i][1] - 50))
    print(distanceToMid)

button4 = Tk.Button(master=root, text="Distance to mid", command=distancemid)
button4.pack(side=Tk.LEFT)

Tk.mainloop()
# If you put root.destroy() here, it will cause an error if
# the window is closed with the window manager.
```

My problem is that the growing time of the first point is much faster than the second and the third growing and so on, if defined. Is it possible that all growings are at the same speed.
Is it possible to hide the first growing Circle instead of overlapping with a white rectancle ans setting the setted nodes?

Comment: Why are you incrementing i and j inside your for loops? The for loop will increment them for you. If you wish i or j to increment by more than 1 each time, you tell `range` to do that for you.

Comment: Can you provide a complete and executable version of your code? It is impossible to test this without executable code.

Comment: Ouh, thank you for your help.

Comment: I have updated my code above.

Comment: I have implemented a timer, which measures the time for each circle. For example the times for three circle are: [7.4,17.1,26.94]. Is it possible to make the time constant for all circles?

Comment: I have changed my starpositioning-function. Now it deletes the circle after each j in range. Seems to work fine for me.